# How to create a new data frame containing the sum-product of matching rows to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, matching, sumproduct

I have two dataframes that contain two types of information. The first is a site by species contingency table that contains the count of particular species at a particular site:

```
> sp
        Sp 1     Sp 2    Sp 3
Site 1    1        2       1
Site 2    0        0       1
Site 3    3        0       0
```

The second is a dataframe of those same species, but with a binary variable that indicates if that species has a particular attribute:

```
> tr
        Tr 1    Tr 2    Tr 3
Sp 1      1      0        0
Sp 2      0      1        0
Sp 3      0      1        1
```

The desired output is a new dataframe that contains the sites, and the sumproduct of the binary trait variable * the frequency of the species at that particular site, as follows:

```
> fu
         Tr 1    Tr 2    Tr 3
Site 1     1       3       1
Site 2     0       1       1
Site 3     3       0       0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

I've tried a few things including the .mul function in pandas; however, matching the species name across multiple attributes and generating the sum product has proven difficult.

Here is code to recreate the above data:

```py
sp = pd.DataFrame({"SiteCode": ["Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3"],
                   "Sp1": [1, 0, 3],
                   "Sp2": [2, 0, 0],
                   "Sp3": [1, 1, 0]})

print(sp)

tr = pd.DataFrame({"SpeciesCode": ["Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp3"],
                   "T1": [1, 0, 0],
                   "T2": [0, 1, 1],
                   "T3": [0, 0, 1]})

print(tr)
```

Comment: Can you explain mathematically how Site 1, Tr 2 equals 3 in fu dataframe?

Comment: Sure, Site 1 has 1 of species 1, 2 of species 2, and 1 of species 3. Trait 2 is expressed only by species 2 and species 3, and not by species 1. The result in Site 1, Tr 2 is of (2 * 1) [for 2 of species 2] + (1 * 1) [for 1 of species 3] = 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay let's use `set_index` and `dot`:

```
sp1 = sp.set_index('SiteCode')

tr1 = tr.set_index('SpeciesCode')

sp1.dot(tr1)
```

Output:

```
          T1  T2  T3
SiteCode            
Site 1     1   3   1
Site 2     0   1   1
Site 3     3   0   0
```

Comment: Oh nice! There always seems to be a simple solution after all! Many thanks!